# Why adding locate('"', ProductName)>0 when trying to remove leading and trailing quotes?

Tags: mysql

```
-- Remove leading and trailing double quotes from productname
SELECT ProductName, TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM ProductName) AS ProductName_trim
FROM superstore.product
WHERE LOCATE('"', ProductName) > 0
ORDER BY LENGTH(ProductName);
```

Here is one of the result record:

```
"Elite 5"" Scissors", Elite 5"" Scissors
```

Doesn't the first " locate at position 0 in the origin ProductName?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the purpose of the query is to only show results there the `trim()` might be doing something.

In SQL, the counting of positions in a string (generally) starts at 1, not 0.  0 is used to indicate that there is no match.

I would suggest writing it as:

```
SELECT p.ProductName, TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM p.ProductName) AS ProductName_trim
FROM superstore.product p
WHERE p.ProductName LIKE '%"%'
ORDER BY LENGTH(p.ProductName);
```

I think the intention is clearer using `LIKE`.

Comment: That's a nice solution. But I don't understand why adding `WHERE LOCATE('"', ProductName) > 0` also works. As you mentioned string starts at 1, but LOCATE returns the substring position. So what >0 means then?

Comment: @user8314628 . . . "0 is used to indicate that there is no match."